# Returning binary '1' at index of minimum value

Tags: python, list, numpy, min

I have an np array with shape (50,2)

so for each row, I'm trying to get the index of the minimum value which I think I managed to
roughly

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
list(my_list[i]).index(min(my_list[i]))
```

however, I am getting a brain block on how to insert '1' at the index of the minimum value?

for e.g

```
([[2,4],
 [5,3]])

will give the index values for the  min(my_list) as 
0
1
```

then the first row will have the index being 0 and the 2nd row will be 1

how do I insert a binary value at the index of the min value so that the output is like

```
[1,0]
[0,1] 
.
.
.
```

thank you!

Comment: Can I ask why don't you use the `where` function instead? Or a simple `filter` for that matter?

Comment: `(-mylist).argsort()`? Please include a [MRE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for the indices of the rows and [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) for the indices of the columns:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[2, 4],
                [5, 3]])

res = np.zeros_like(arr)
res[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), arr.argmin(axis=1)] = 1
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

Comment: thank you for this! interesting method - I was looking initially at using for loops but this works just as well, if not better

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant and readable way to go about your problem is to first, copy your array into another one, then switch the columns in the second array and just simply use the logical operators to get what you want. Take a look at the code below:

```py
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array([[2, 4],
                    [5, 3]])

my_list_swaped = my_list.copy()
my_list_swaped [ : , [0,1]] = my_list_swaped[ : ,[1,0]]  #Swapping the columns

print( my_list < my_list_swaped )
```

What you will get is:

```py
array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True]])
```

which is basically:

```
array([[ 1, 0],
       [0,  1]])
```

**Simplifying the code:**
If you don't have a problem doing it *the dirty way* (less readable way), you can directly use the logical operator along with indexing to get what you want:

```py
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array([[2, 4],
                    [5, 3]])
result = my_list < my_list[ : , [1,0] ]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use argmin together with the identity-matrix-one-hot trick:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
exmpl = rng.integers(0,10,(4,2))
exmpl
# array([[4, 0],
#        [8, 5],
#        [1, 3],
#        [3, 0]])

np.identity(2,int)[exmpl.argmin(1)]
# array([[0, 1],
#        [0, 1],
#        [1, 0],
#        [0, 1]])
```